# Table not showing all columns in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to add table I first generated migration file.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :users do |t|
        t.string "email", :limit => 50, :null => false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Then i go to command line and type rake :db miagrate
I get this message

```
== 20150316003101 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0098s
== 20150316003101 CreateUsers: migrated (0.0098s) =============================
```

Then i go to my sql and go to my db and check table and email column is not there. This is what i see.

```
describe users;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I should also see email type string in there but i don't . Can anyone tell me what i could have done wrong? This is my first day using ruby on rails so it might be something very silly.

Comment: Possibly, you're looking at the wrong database. Can you verify that the database.yml development entry matches the DB you are inspecting?

Comment: development:
  <<: *default
  database: readit_development

Comment: yes and below i posted the tutorial i am following

Comment: @PinnyM please let me know if you require further information..

Comment: Does your db/schema.rb file reflect the new columns in this table, or is it missing there as well?

Comment: it is missing in the schema.rb as well @PinnyM

Comment: Very interesting.  I'd recommend remigrating using `rake db:migrate:redo` - please post back with your results.

Comment: @PinnyM so just to update you i tried a new approach i generated a model using rails g model name title:int, etc and this way it worked. i checked sql and it shows up my fields in the table. I have no idea why the other one did not work. any ideas? just good to know these things since i am new.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email, :limit => 50, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried, same thing no change.. is there some ...i am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GY7Ps8fqGdc

Comment: about 26 minutes in to it he creates it.